"Elegant" conditions on two quadratics (with positive real roots) to ensure that the larger root of one is less than the smaller root of the other
I have two quadratic equations, both with two real roots ( discriminant > 0). Additionally the roots are all positive numbers.
$$ ax^2 + bx + c = 0  $$
$$ dx^2 + ex + f = 0 $$
Is there an elegant way to state the conditions in the parameters $ {a,b,c,d,e,f} $ such that the largest root of one of the equations is always less than the lowest solution of the other equation. I could write this as
$$ \frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a} < \frac{-e - \sqrt{e^2 -4df}}{2d} $$
But I wonder if there is a nicer way to express this.

@lonzaleggiera I think that you have a typo in the comment.  So the original poster doesn't get confused, it should be $$\frac{-e + \sqrt{e^2 - 4df}}{2d} < \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}.$$

@user2661923 (Yes, poor proof reading on my part (there was also "altetnative").  Thanks for picking it up.)  To rodrigo:  The condition you give is the condition that the largest root of the first equation be less than the smallest root of the second. The condition that the largest root on one of them be smaller than the smallest root of the other would be the disjunction of that condition with the alternative $$\frac{-e +\sqrt{e^2 -4df}}{2d} < \frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}\ .$$

Note that reducing the quadratics to the monic form (by multiplying $1/a$ and $1/d$ respectively) doesn’t change the roots, so without loss of generality, let’s assume that the quadratics are
\begin{align}
&f(x) = x^2+ p x + q = 0\\
&g(x) = x^2+ u x + v = 0.
\end{align}
Now the larger root of one of them is smaller than the smaller root of the other if and only if there’s a point $x_0$ such that
\begin{align}
&f(x_0) = g(x_0) \ge 0,\\
&f’(x_0)g’(x_0) < 0.
\end{align}
This is easy to see by looking at the graphs of the two quadratics.
In fact, since the two quadratics are in the monic form, they intersect at exactly one point given by
$$
f(x_0) = g(x_0) \implies x_0 = -\frac{q-v}{p-u}.
$$
(Note that $p\ne u$ because the two quadratics should attain their minima at different points for the desired situation to be possible, and moreover, $x_0$ is between these two minima.) Substituting $x_0$ into the above inequalities gives the desired conditions.

Update:
I just noticed the precalculus tag, so talking about $f’$ and $g’$ isn’t allowed. But actually, the second inequality is just the statement that $x_0$ is between the minima of $f$ and $g$.

Let's use monic polynomials with the same roots as the original quadratic polynomials.
By taking $B=-\dfrac b{2a}$, $C=\dfrac ca$, $E = -\dfrac e{2d}$, and $F = \dfrac fd$ we get
\begin{align}
P_1(x) &= x^2 - 2Bx + C, \\
P_2(x) &= x^2 - 2Ex + F.
\end{align}
Note that $B$ and $E$ are respectively the values of $x$ at which $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$ are minimized.
Let the roots of $P_1(x) = 0$ be $r_1, r_2$ (with $r_1 \leq B \leq r_2$)
and the roots of $P_2(x) = 0$ be $s_1, s_2$ (with $s_1 \leq E \leq s_2$).
You want to know when the closed intervals $[r_1,r_2]$ and $[s_1,s_2]$ are disjoint.

One approach has already been offered. It works as follows.
The two polynomials are equal when $x = \dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}.$
Note that we are guaranteed to have an intersection if $B\neq E$.
(If $B = E$ then of course it is not possible for the greater root of one polynomial to be less than the lesser root of the other polynomial.)
Since $P_1(x)$ is positive when $x$ is outside $[r_1,r_2]$
and $P_2(x)$ is positive when $x$ is outside $[s_1,s_2]$, if
$P_1\left(\dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}\right)
 = P_2\left(\dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}\right) \leq 0$
then $x = \dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}$ belongs to both $[r_1,r_2]$ and $[s_1,s_2]$,
which therefore are not disjoint intervals.
This implies that
$$P_1\left(\dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}\right)
 = P_2\left(\dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}\right) > 0  \tag1 $$
is a necessary condition for the intervals $[r_1,r_2]$ and $[s_1,s_2]$
to be disjoint.
But Inequality $(1)$ is not a sufficient condition. Consider
$P_1(x) = x^2 - 2x$ and $P_2(x) = x^2 - 4x - \dfrac94$.
In that case, $\dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)} = -\dfrac98$, and while it is true that
$P_1\left(-\dfrac98\right) = P_2\left(-\dfrac98\right) > 0$,
it is also true that the roots of $P_1(x)=0$ are $\{0,2\}$ and the roots of $P_2(x)=0$ are $\left\{-0.5,4.5\right\}$, and the intervals
$[0,2]$ and $[0.5,4.5]$ certainly overlap.
So a further condition is necessary. One such condition is that
$\dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}$ is between $B$ and $E$.
That would imply that a point in neither $[r_1,r_2]$ nor $[s_1,s_2]$
is between points in $[r_1,r_2]$ and $[s_1,s_2]$ respectively, and therefore
$[r_1,r_2]$ and $[s_1,s_2]$ do not overlap.
But if you really want to be sure the greater root of one polynomial is less than the lesser root of the other polynomial, you need to be sure that both polynomials have real roots. So that's two more conditions to check if you did not already do so while setting up the problem.
The reason these conditions are necessary is that the polynomials
$x^2 - 2x + 2$ and $x^2 - 4x + 5$ have the same value at $x = \dfrac32$, which is between the minimum values of the polynomials as required, but neither polynomial has any real roots.
Below is another approach.

Observe that the roots of $P_1(x)=0$ are $B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - C}$
and the roots of $P_2(x)=0$ are $E \pm \sqrt{E^2 - F}$.
The interval between $B$ and $E$ must contain half of the interval $[r_1,r_2]$,
half of the interval $[s_1,s_2]$, plus an additional interval of some length between $[r_1,r_2]$ and $[s_1,s_2]$. This implies that
$$ \sqrt{B^2 - C} + \sqrt{E^2 - F} < \lvert B - E \rvert. \tag2 $$
If you're willing to deal with a couple of square roots, this is all you need.
Inequality $(2)$ is both a necessary and sufficient condition.

But if you really want to get rid of the square roots, we can do that.
To begin with, note that necessary conditions for both polynomials to have roots and for $[r_1,r_2]$ and $[s_1,s_2]$ to be disjoint are
$$
\begin{align}
 C &\leq B^2,  \tag3 \\
 F &\leq E^2,  \tag4 \\
 B &\neq E.    \tag5
\end{align}
$$
(All of these are consequences of $(2)$ being a true statement.)
Noting that both sides of $(2)$ are non-negative, we can square both sides while preserving the direction of the inequality. We get
$$ B^2 - C + E^2 - F + 2\sqrt{(B^2 - C)(E^2 - F)} < B^2 + E^2 - 2BE. \tag6 $$
Add $C + F - B^2 - E^2$ to both sides of $(6)$:
$$ 2\sqrt{(B^2 - C)(E^2 - F)} < C + F - 2BE. \tag7 $$
This implies that
$$ C + F > 2BE \tag8 $$
since the left-hand side of $(7)$ is guaranteed to be positive.
This means that Inequality $(8)$ is also a necessary condition for the intervals between the roots not to overlap.
Note that in the example given earlier
($P_1(x) = x^2 - 2x$, $P_2(x) = x^2 - 4x - \dfrac94$), where the graphs of the polynomials intersect above the $x$ axis but the roots overlap,
Inequality $(6)$ is violated.
If $(8)$ is true, that is, if $C + F > 2BE$, square both sides of $(7)$.
Since both sides are non-negative, this does not change the direction of the inequality, which becomes
$$ 4(B^2 - C)(E^2 - F) < C^2 + 2 C F + F^2 + 4 B^2 E^2 - 4 B C E - 4 B E F. \tag9 $$
Collect all the terms of $(9)$ on one side of the inequality and it can be simplified to
$$ (C - F)^2 + 4(B - E)(BF - CE) > 0. \tag{10} $$
We now have a set of conditions that must be true. We can simplify these a little by noting that $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(8)$ imply $B^2 + E^2 > 2BE$, which implies $(3)$.
If we have $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(8)$ we can take $(10)$ and successively rearrange the terms from one side to the other, take the positive square root on each side two times (with additional rearrangement between those two occasions), and derive $(2)$.
Therefore the four conditions $(3)$, $(4)$, $(8)$, and $(10)$ are both necessary and sufficient. In summary, the conditions are
\begin{gather}
 C \leq B^2,  \\
 F \leq E^2,  \\
C + F > 2BE, \\
(C - F)^2 + 4(B - E)(BF - CE) > 0.
\end{gather}
That's four inequalities instead of one, but you don't have to do any square roots in order to check these conditions.

Not so coincidentally, if we take the value $x = \dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}$
from the first solution method and plug it into one of the polynomials,
say $P_1(x)$, we get
\begin{align}
P_1\left(\dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}\right)
&= \left(\dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)}\right)^2 - 2B \dfrac{C - F}{2(B - E)} + C \\
&= \dfrac{(C - F)^2 + 4(B - E)(B F - C E)}{4(B - E)^2}.
\end{align}
This value is positive if and only if both conditions $(5)$ (so that the value exists) and $(10)$ are true. But in order to have non-overlapping sets of roots we also need conditions $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(8)$, which were the missing conditions in the first approach.
